# Spatially constrained multivariate clustering in ArcPy gives AttributeError?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, clustering, spatial-cluster

i want to use the Spatially constrained multivariate clustering tool for a point shapefile. I'm using PyScripter. The shapefile is named "LITO2016_area_modelli_20190312_v2" and the attribute fields i want to use in the analysis are "Rvmedian", "Rv_int_ran" and "zero". Prova is the output field. Arcpy give me this error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute
>   'SpatiallyConstrainedMultivariateClustering_stats'

I don't know where i'm wrong.

```
import arcpy
    from arcpy import env
    from arcpy.sa import *
    #Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
    arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\python'
    arcpy.SpatiallyConstrainedMultivariateClustering_stats("LITO2016_area_modelli_20190312_v2", "prova", None, "Rvmedian", "Rv_int_ran", "zero", None, None, None,"CONTIGUITY_EDGES_CORNERS")
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You imported say functions already, so use it without arcpy. Or use arcpy.sa, but no of arguments could be different

Answer (score 1):

[Seems like](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/spatially-constrained-multivariate-clustering.htm#C_GUID-851C1672-7A54-41C2-931E-464EAA5E7437) the correct name of the function is

```
arcpy.stats.SpatiallyConstrainedMultivariateClustering
```

In general, when you get an error: " 'module' object has no attribute X", it means that there is no function named X in the library/module/class, which means you probably have written something wrong in the name of the function, which should be quick to find in the corresponding module's documentation.

Comment: thnk you for your reply, it is well explained. I tried to change the name of the function like you suggest but it give the same error.